# WCF Binding in web.config gives HTTP-fejl 500.19 - Internal Server Error on Windows 7

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config, wcf-binding

I am deploying my site locally to the IIS on my Windows 7 machine, which has been working for a month now. All the necessary features are installed, ASP.NET is activated and so on. I also activated the WCF features.

Now I am trying to host a WCF service. While running it in Visual Studio, it works perfectly (except for some other problems I already asked about on SO). However, on my IIS it gives the following IIS error:

> HTTP-fejl 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
>
> : The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid. Error Code: 0x80070005
>   Notification: BeginRequest Module: IIS Web Core Requested URL:
>   ... Physical Path:
>   ... Logon
>   User: Not yet determined Logon Method: Not yet determined Handler: Not
>   yet determined Config Error: Cannot read configuration file Config
>   File: ... Config
>   Source:

Now, this is my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="ForumOperationService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IForumOperationService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
      <add name="AjaxToolkit" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

And this is my WCF webservice test:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ForumOperationService : IForumOperationService
{

    public string Horse(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        return "hestWCF";
    }

    public List<SystemTagDTO> GetTags(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        var dfasd = new List<SystemTagDTO>();
        dfasd.Add(new SystemTagDTO() { Isvisible = true, Value = "Aktant" });
        dfasd.Add(new SystemTagDTO() { Isvisible = true, Value = "Beretter" });
        return dfasd;
    }
}
```

I can see that the error is removed when I remove the behaviours/services + handler entry.

Now, my question is: Why does it work in VS 2012, and not on my local IIS? Should I somehow set the WCF service to be hosted on the IIS directly? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there is a mistake in your configuration file. WCF related config elements like behaviors, serviceHostingEnvironment & services should be with in **`<system.ServiceModel>`** tag and not within **`<system.webServer>`**. Try fixing that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah sorry, wrong copy paste. It is in side the serviceModel of course :-) Same error.